# Sticky animation not working properly in Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, sticky

If you test this in Firefox, whether by scrolling or clicking the text box, everything works fine, but in the other browsers I've listed the text box jumps to the bottom before the animation starts.

Not sure what's causing this to happen or how to fix it, any ideas?

```
function stickyStuff(){
var half_height = $(window).height()/2+8;
$('#check1').sticky({
    'offset'  : half_height,
    'mode'   : 'animate',
    'speed' : 500,
    'onStick' : function() { 
    $('#front-title-wrap').animate({ 'top': '50px' }); 
    }
});
$('#check2').sticky({
    'offset'  : 55,
    'onStick' : function() { 
    $('#front-nav-wrapper').css({'position' : 'fixed','top': '55px', 'opacity' : '1' }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it causes the problem, you are including the same sticky js file twice. normal version and min version.

Remove one and test again?

## Your script

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://coreytegeler.com/gl/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://coreytegeler.com/gl/js/jquery.sticky.min.js"></script>
```